# Returning a call to a pointer to a function in C

Tags: c, pointers

From the book *21st Century C*:

> Conceptually, the syntax for a function type is really a pointer to a function of a given type. If you have a function with a header like:
>
> ```
> double a_fn(int, in); //a declaration
> ```
>
> then just add a star (and parens to resolve precedence) to describe a pointer to this type of function:
>
> ```
>  double (*a_fn_type)(int, int); //a type: pointer-to-function
> ```
>
> Then put typedef in front of that to define a type:
>
> ```
>  typedef double (*a_fn_type)(int, int); //a typedef for a pointer to function
> ```
>
> Now you can use it as a type like any other, such as to declare a function that takes another function as input:
>
> ```
> double apply_a_fn(a_fn_type f, int first_in, int second_in){
>   return f(first_in, second_in); //shouldn't this be *f(first_in, second_in) ?
> }
> ```

**Question:** Shouldn't the return value of this very last function be `*f(first_in, second_in)`, since `f` is a pointer to a function and `*f` denotes the actual function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dereferencing operator for calling a function pointer is [optional in C](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#call).

Comment: So, to be clear, in the context of this question either `return f(first_in, second_in)` or `return *f(first_in, second_in)` is correct?

Comment: I believe it would be (*f)(first_in, second_in), but yes. Why don't you give it a try?